# Convoluted derivative and ambiguous question

Tags: calculus

I've encountered this question: Find the derivative  $ \frac{ dP}{dt} $ for $ P = \frac{mv}{\sqrt({1-(v^2/c^2})} $ where $ m $ and  $ c$  are constants, and $ v $ depends on $ t$ .

I got this result: $\frac{ (mc^2(1-(t^2/c^2) - mt^3)}{((c^2)*(\sqrt(1-t^2/c^2))} - ((t^2)*\sqrt((1-t^2)/c^2))  $ 
I am new to derivatives so I am pretty sure I missed up somewhere. Could anyone check my result?
Also, the question is quite vague: "$v$ depends on $t$". What does that mean? Does it means something I don't know? I just did $ v = t $.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, " $v$ depends on $t$ " this does not imply that $v=t$, in deed, it means that $v$ is a function of $t$, and you may write $ v=v(t)$. So when deriving wrt $t$, $\frac{dv}{dt}= v'(t)$.

Now, returning to $P$, we have  $$ P(t)= \frac{m v(t)}{ \sqrt{1-\frac{v(t)^2}{c^2}}}$$
 we have $P(t)=\frac{mv}{\sqrt({1-(v^2/c^2})}$ then $P$ is a fraction and thus to drive we follow the following rule $$ {\frac{u}{v}}'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$ thus $$ P'(t)= \frac{ (mv'(t))(\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2})-(mv(t))(\frac{-2v(t)v'(t)/c^2}{2 *\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}})}{1-v^2/c^2}​= \frac{ c^2 (mv'(t) ) ( 1-v^2/c^2) + m v(t)^2 v'(t) }{ c^2 (1-v^2/c^2) \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now, if my derivation above is correct, I just have to replace the t with v(t) and I should be fine, right?

Comment: I think you would need a little more effort, since in this case you will have the term $ v'(t)$ , which was $1$ in your solution. And Also I think you have a small computation error in your calculation. So I advice you to try it again and let us see the new results :)

Comment: I'll get to it right away!

Comment: Just to be sure, the derivative of m*v(t) should be v'(t), right?

Comment: indeed  $mv'(t) $ since $ m $ is a constant : example derivative of $2* (t^2)$ is $ 2*(2t)$.

Comment: I got this result: (mv'(t)*sqrt(1-(v^2(t)/c^2)))*(2sqrt(1-(v^2(t)/c^2))-mv(t)*2v'(t))/(2sqrt(1-(v^2(t)/c^2)*(1-(v^2/c^2)        is that right? If no, could you post your result? thanks!

Comment: I edit my answer, please  @ArthurRimbaud check it